# Implementing Dynamic Memory Management Functions

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I tryed to implement dynamic memory managemet functions and succeed. However when I try to implement another function that prints some information about memory with the exact same way, I got segmentation fault. I am using Ubuntu, gcc.

Here is my related code:

In mm_alloc.c: (Other functions malloc, free etc. are also here)

```
#include "mm_alloc.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#include "string.h"

void mm_print_mem() {

   printf( "\nstart_addr\tsize\tfree\tprev\tnext\n");
   printf("=============================\n");

    printf("HEAD OF LL %p\n", metadata);
    METADATA *currentPtr = metadata;
    int i = 0;
    while (currentPtr!= NULL  && i <= 10) {
        printf("%p\t%d\t%d\t%p\t%p\n", currentPtr, (int)currentPtr-
>size, currentPtr->free,currentPtr->prev,currentPtr->next);
        if (currentPtr->next == NULL) break;
        currentPtr = currentPtr->next;
        i++;
    }
    return;
}
```

mm_alloc.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct METADATA{
    struct METADATA *next;
    struct METADATA *prev;
    int free;
    size_t size;
}METADATA;

METADATA *metadata;

void *mm_malloc(size_t size);
void *mm_realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
void mm_free(void *ptr);
void mm_print_mem();
```

And the test function. Here, I got segmentation fault when I call mm_print_mem function, others work well.

```
int main() {
    load_alloc_functions();

    int *dizi = (int *)mm_malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
    dizi[4] = 5;
    dizi[2] = 10;
    printf("%d - %d\n", dizi[4], dizi[2]);
    mm_print_mem();

    return 0;
}
```

I use these commands on Ubuntu in order to link files and run the test file.

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic mm_alloc.c
gcc -shared -o libfoo.so 14011085.so
gcc mm_test.c -o try -ldl
./try
```

Notice that even the inside of mm_print_mem was empty, it gives segmentation fault as well. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You really have a local header `"stdlib.h"`?? and `"stdio.h"`?? and ...?? Seems like you are mistaking the `"` for `<>`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It works well without adding mm_print_mem function. But I change after saw your comment but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: Let me take a closer look. Also, why are you declaring `metadata` as a global pointer instead of declaring in `main()` and passing as a parameter to your functions, as required? (and it's `-Wextra` not `-Werror`)

Comment: Because I want that user should not interact with metadata informations, just the allocation functions that they should see. And -Wextra did not work as well.

Comment: Well, whether you passing the list as a parameter prevents just as much user interaction with the metadata information as declaring it global does (and you avoid potential name collisions, etc.) Yes, `-Werror` is fine when creating a shared object lib, I glossed over that part until I looked close at what you were doing. Take a look at the example and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make things a bit difficult by not providing a [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but a short example will help. Without seeing your `load` and `alloc` functions, you leave us guessing a bit at exactly where your problem is located or the extent of you problems.

That said a short example illustrating your `mm_print_mem();` function should at least get that part straightened out. (**note:** the example uses a *cirular linked list* where the last node points to the first and first->prev points to the last. You can adjust the test and assignments for `metadata->prev` and `last->next` if you want `NULL` at both ends)

While you can use `#pragma once`, you will find greater portability just using traditional header-guards to prevent multiple includes, e.g. `#ifndef HEADERNAME`, then `#define` it, e.g.

```
#ifndef  __mm_alloc_h__
#define  __mm_alloc_h__  1

#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct METADATA {
    struct METADATA *next;
    struct METADATA *prev;
    int free;
    size_t size;
} METADATA;

METADATA *metadata;

// void *mm_malloc(size_t size);
// void *mm_realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
// void mm_free(void *ptr);
void mm_print_mem();

#endif
```

Your `mm_alloc.c` is fine, but your loop control was a bit strange with the *magic number* `10` included as a condition. With the example list, you simply iterate and increment nodes until `currentPtr->next` (e.g. `currentPtr` after assignment) is equal to `metadata` (completing the circle)

```
#include "mm_alloc.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void mm_print_mem() {

    METADATA *currentPtr = metadata;

    printf ("\nstart_addr\tsize\tfree\tprev\t\tnext\n"
            "=========================================================\n"
            "HEAD OF LL %p\n", metadata);

    for (;;) {
        printf ("%p\t%d\t%d\t%p\t%p\n", currentPtr, (int)currentPtr->size,
                currentPtr->free,currentPtr->prev,currentPtr->next);
        currentPtr = currentPtr->next;
        if (currentPtr == metadata)
            break;
    }
}
```

I wrote a simple test program that allocates and fills `20` nodes for you showing the independent handling of the 1st and remaining nodes, e.g,

```
#include "mm_alloc.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 20

int main (void) {

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        METADATA *node = malloc (sizeof *node);
        if (!node) {
            perror ("malloc node");
            return 1;
        }
        node->next = node->prev = NULL;
        node->free = MAX - i - 1;
        node->size = i;

        if (!metadata) {        /* 1st node is self-referencing */
            node->prev = node;  /* in circular linked-list */
            node->next = node;
            metadata = node;
        }
        else {  /* add rest at end as metadata->prev */
            node->prev = metadata->prev;
            node->next = metadata;
            metadata->prev->next = node;
            metadata->prev = node;
        }
    }
    mm_print_mem();

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** you should free the node when you are done with them)

**Compile Shared Object Library & Test Program**

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -fPIC -o mm_alloc.o -c mm_alloc.c
$ gcc -shared -o libmm_alloc.so mm_alloc.o
```

When compiling the test program, make sure your program can find your shared library. using the linker option `-rpath` is a good way to specify the location for a custom library if not in the standard library search path locations. (just note it must be in the same place on any system you copy it too)

(line-continuation are used below to allow the compile string to fit)

```
$ gcc -L"/path/to/your/lib/dir" \
  -Wl,-rpath="/path/to/your/lib/dir" \
  -Wall -o mm_alloc_tst mm_alloc_tst.c -lmm_alloc
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./mm_alloc_tst

start_addr      size    free    prev            next
=========================================================
HEAD OF LL 0x208d010
0x208d010       0       19      0x208d3a0       0x208d040
0x208d040       1       18      0x208d010       0x208d070
0x208d070       2       17      0x208d040       0x208d0a0
0x208d0a0       3       16      0x208d070       0x208d0d0
0x208d0d0       4       15      0x208d0a0       0x208d100
0x208d100       5       14      0x208d0d0       0x208d130
0x208d130       6       13      0x208d100       0x208d160
0x208d160       7       12      0x208d130       0x208d190
0x208d190       8       11      0x208d160       0x208d1c0
0x208d1c0       9       10      0x208d190       0x208d1f0
0x208d1f0       10      9       0x208d1c0       0x208d220
0x208d220       11      8       0x208d1f0       0x208d250
0x208d250       12      7       0x208d220       0x208d280
0x208d280       13      6       0x208d250       0x208d2b0
0x208d2b0       14      5       0x208d280       0x208d2e0
0x208d2e0       15      4       0x208d2b0       0x208d310
0x208d310       16      3       0x208d2e0       0x208d340
0x208d340       17      2       0x208d310       0x208d370
0x208d370       18      1       0x208d340       0x208d3a0
0x208d3a0       19      0       0x208d370       0x208d010
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least a problem in the declaration of the global variable `metadata`. It is declared as `METADATA *metadata;` in an **included** file. So it has correctly external linkage, but is *defined* in every translation unit, when one single *definition* should exist in a full program. Not doing so is explicitely undefined behaviour, with no diagnostic required.

There are different ways to fix that problem:

- declare it extern in the include file

  ```
  extern METADATA *metadata;
  ```

  and define it in only one translation unit without the `extern` specifier:

  ```
  #include "mm_alloc.h"    // extern declaration
  ...
  METADATA * metadata;     // single definition in whole program
  ```
- put all the library functions in one single translation unit (if it makes sense), *define* `metadata` in that file and remove any reference to it from the mm_alloc.h file. After all, it is private data for the library...
- remove the reference to `metadata` from the mm_alloc.h include file which should only declare the external interface for the library, *define* it in one single file of the library (at file level without the `extern` specifier) and *declare* it in all other files from the library as `extern METADATA *metadata;`

Without seeing the source for the other functions I cannot say whether there are other problems...

Comment: Thanks for the answer.